# Hot to write Unit Test case for SqlDataReader using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I have following methods and want to write the Unit test case for mapping result through DataReader.

```
public interface IIMGAdvancedSearchDBProvider
{
    clsGPAdvancedSearchResult GetSearchResult(clsIMGAdvancedImageSearchCriteria searchCriteria);
}

public class clsIMGAdvancedSearchSQLDBProvider : IIMGAdvancedSearchDBProvider
{
    public clsGLGJSearchResultItem GetSearchResult(clsIMGAdvancedImageSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {   
        using (var sqlConnection = DfxDbConnection)
        {
            using (var sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@userKey", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = State.WebUserKey;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@SiteCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = State.SiteCode;
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@MaxRows", SqlDbType.Int).Value = searchCriteria.MaxRows;

                //Add required client, client group filter paramters
                AddClientAndClientGroupFilterParameters(searchCriteria, sqlCommand);

                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCommand.CommandText = GetCompleteSQLStatement(searchCriteria);

                var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                return alTransaction(reader);

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private clsGLGJSearchResultItem GetJournalTransaction(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        return new clsGLGJSearchResultItem
        {

            ClientKey = DfxUtilities.GetGuidValueFromReader(reader, "ClientKey") ?? Guid.Empty,
            JournalId = DfxUtilities.GetLongValueFromReader(reader, "JournalID") ?? 0,
            AccountingDate = (DateTime)reader["Date"],

            JournalSource =
                (enumJournalSources)
                Enum.Parse(typeof(enumJournalSources), reader["Source"].ToString()),

            Description = DfxUtilities.GetStringValueFromReader(reader, "Description"),
            DebitAmount = DfxUtilities.GetDecimalValueFromReader(reader, "DebitAmount") ?? 0,
            CreditAmount = DfxUtilities.GetDecimalValueFromReader(reader, "CreditAmount") ?? 0,
            ClientCode = DfxUtilities.GetStringValueFromReader(reader, "ClientCode"),
            ClientName = DfxUtilities.GetStringValueFromReader(reader, "ClientName"),

            Images = GetImageItems(reader)
        };
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Comment: What are you trying resolve?

Comment: I want to write test cases for SqlDataReader mapping.

Comment: SO is not your subcontractor.  If you have a specific problem about a test you've written, or have a question about research you've done about how to test your relevant code, then those may be on topic.

Comment: I want to mock var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(); but unable to event start the test cases, can not thing from where to start.

Comment: @Sharad Those classes have already been extensively tested by MS. No need reinventing the wheel. review your design and abstract the data access if needed otherwise what you describe is more of an integration test as apposed to a unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be better off treating your data abstraction layer (DAL) interfaces and classes  (like `IIMGAdvancedSearchDBProvider` and `clsIMGAdvancedSearchSQLDBProvider`) as components that you **integration test** rather than **unit test**.

In other words, combine testing of the database schema, triggers, seed test data + your DAL implementation class (including the call to `ExecuteReader`).  DALs should be thin and exclude business logic as yours does. You'd typically setup/teardown test data in the database for these integration tests. You might also want to create a common base class for these DAL integration test classes to setup your test database connection and perhaps some SQL logging. Might also maintain a separate test database with edge test case data or otherwise inject this data in setup/teardowns.  No Mocking here.

Then you can **unit test** the business layer classes above it by mocking the values returned by your DAL interface `IIMGAdvancedSearchDBProvider` in the components/classes that use the DAL interface. I often try to complete the DAL testing first and capture some snapshots of "real production data" cases that I then return from my Mock DAL objects to the business layer unit tests.  This avoids creating Mocks that miss the real data edge cases that are in the production data.

If you're using NUnit, consider using their `TestCase`, `Pairwise` and `Combinatorial` attributes to generated test cases (rather than mocking them) for your business layer objects.  You might also find my [ShouldBe](https://github.com/tohagan/ShouldBe) wrapper library handy.

BTW ... Your `cls` class prefix naming convention is non-standard.